# How do i actually get the translated file onto my computer using IBM Watson translate document function

Tags: python, api, ibm-watson, translate

I'm using IBM Watson translate API in python to translate a pdf document i've got to a point where i'm getting a return from get_translated_document() and its returning 200 Success with a Detailed response object. I don't know how to actually get the translated document onto my computer. Thanks in advance.

```
   print(json.dumps(list_of_documents, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
   language_translator.set_detailed_response(True)
   response = language_translator.get_translated_document('api-key', 
   accept='application/pdf')

   #f= open(translateddoc,"rb")
   #contents = f.read()

   if response.status_code == 200:
     if response.headers.get('Content-Disposition'):
        print("Got file in response")
        print("Writing file to filename.bin")
        print(response)

     params = cgi.parse_header(
        response.headers.get('Content-Disposition', ''))[-1]
     print (response.Response())
     if 'filename' not in params:
        raise ValueError('Could not find a filename')
     filename = os.path.basename(params['filename'])
     abs_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using get_translated_document function, to see how to use it, check out [this link](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/language-translator?code=python#get-translated-document).

Or you can try the steps in the [this link](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/language-translator?topic=language-translator-document-translator-tutorial&_ga=2.213400083.647852888.1570700193-1168043908.1570700193&cm_mc_uid=30756186832815706993476&cm_mc_sid_50200000=21560171570700192286&cm_mc_sid_52640000=57794091570700192298#document-translator-tutorial) so that you will not need to write any script for the translation of a document.